# setting for line graphs for graph charts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a graph similar to [this chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic). My question is when the graph is loading can I have it only show one line instead of all. I didn't see anything on the API or probably missed it.

This is part of the ajax call I have

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    chart.addSeries({
        name: data[i].name,
        data: data[i].data
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `visible: i === 0`? That will hide all series except for the first. See http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.visible

Comment: Or are you asking about the animation?

Comment: If i have several lines, they all show up. I did visible:false and it hides all of them. Is there a way to show certain ones like if(data[i].name == 'something') {visible:true} // I tried that and it didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out:

I did `visible: data[i].name === 'value'`